# Use enum from header in other class

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-14.04

I've got a little problem with my enum.

I wanna create a new Object with an enum as parameter.

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

class A {
    enum myEnum { value1, value2};
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
//code

    function() {
     B* t = new B(myEnum::value1);
    }
```

The following Error message appears:
"myEnum is not a class or namespace"

What's wrong? Sorry for this question, but i am a Newbie.

Comment: It should be `A::value1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would access the `enum` as

```
A::value1
```

Or you could use an [`enum class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cskb49.aspx) like

```
enum class myEnum { value1, value2}
```

And then you'd scope the value as

```
A::myEnum::value1
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the enum declaration public!

Comment: Correct, that is an important detail.

Answer (score 2):

The fully qualified name for `value` would be:

```
A::myEnum::value1
```

But, C++ (before C++11) doesn't allow name of `enum` to be used (depends on compiler, they may emit warning). So, pre C++11, you would need to:

```
A::value1
```

But, the enum (`myEnum`) is not accessible, so you must mark it as `public`.

In C++11 onwards, you better use `enum class` instead, which must be accessed fully-qualified.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    public:
        enum myEnum { value1, value2};
};
```

Add public access specifier as above.
Use it like

```
A::myEnum::value1
```

eventhough the following will work

```
A::value1
```